# I have a problem with loading my app in the simulator. My apps login page appears and after login it shows black and white

Tags: ios, swift

```
 // This is my App delegate file 
    import UIKit
    import Firebase
    import UserNotifications
    
    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
        
        let gcmMessageIDKey = NSUUID().uuidString
    
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            FirebaseApp.configure()
            attemptToRegisterForNotifications(application: application)
            return true
        }
        
        func attemptToRegisterForNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            
            let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: options) { (authorized, error) in
                if authorized {
                    print("DEBUG: SUCCESSFULLY REGISTERED FOR NOTIFICATIONS")
                }
            }
            
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    
        // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle
    
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
            // Called when a new scene session is being created.
            // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
            return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
        }
    
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
            // Called when the user discards a scene session.
            // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
            // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
        }
    
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
          // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
          // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
          // TODO: Handle data of notification
    
          // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
          // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    
          // Print message ID.
          if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
          }
    
          // Print full message.
          print(userInfo)
        }
    
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                         fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
          // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
          // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
          // TODO: Handle data of notification
    
          // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
          // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    
          // Print message ID.
          if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
          }
    
          // Print full message.
          print(userInfo)
    
          completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
        }
    }
    
    extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
            print("DEBUG: Registered for notifications with device token: ", deviceToken)
            Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        }
        
        func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
            print("DEBUG: Regisered with FCM Token: ", fcmToken)
        }
    }
    
    @available(iOS 10, *)
    extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
      // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
      func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                  willPresent notification: UNNotification,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
          print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
    
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    
        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([[.alert, .sound]])
      }
    
      func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                  didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                  withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
          print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
    
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    
        completionHandler()
      }
    }

//This is my scene delegate file.

    import UIKit
    
    class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    
        var window: UIWindow?
    
    
        func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
            guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
            window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
            window?.rootViewController = MainTabController()
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            
        }
    
        func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
            // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
            // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
            // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
            // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not necessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
        }
    
        func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
            // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
            // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
        }
    
        func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
            // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
            // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
        }
    
        func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
            // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
            // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
        }
    
        func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
            // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
            // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
            // to restore the scene back to its current state.
        }
    
    
    }
   

// I have tried resetting the simulator and restarted my laptop. But nothing has worked so far. Hopefully I can get something useful from the SO community.


//Login Controller: Which appears perfectly fine and I am  login using the required credentials. Right after that is when the simulator doesn't show anything except for the weird black and white screen


import UIKit

protocol AuthenticationDelegate: class {
    func authenticationDidComplete()
}

class LoginController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    private var viewModel = LoginViewModel()
    weak var delegate: AuthenticationDelegate?
    
    private let iconImage: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Instagram_logo_white"))
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return iv
    }()
    
    private let emailTextField: CustomTextField = {
        let tf = CustomTextField(placeholder: "Email")
        tf.keyboardType = .emailAddress
        return tf
    }()
    
    private let passwordTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = CustomTextField(placeholder: "Password")
        tf.isSecureTextEntry = true
        return tf
    }()
    
    private let loginButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Log In", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5568627715, green: 0.3529411852, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1).withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.setHeight(50)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        button.isEnabled = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLogin), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    private let forgotPasswordButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.attributedTitle(firstPart: "Forgot your password?", secondPart: "Get help signing in.")
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleShowResetPassword), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    private let dontHaveAccountButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.attributedTitle(firstPart: "Don't have an account?", secondPart: "Sign Up")
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleShowSignUp), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureUI()
        configureNotificationObservers()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Actions
    
    @objc func handleLogin() {
        guard let email = emailTextField.text else { return }
        guard let password = passwordTextField.text else { return }
        
        AuthService.logUserIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("DEBUG: Failed to log user in \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            self.delegate?.authenticationDidComplete()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func handleShowSignUp() {
        let controller = RegistrationController()
        controller.delegate = delegate
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
    
    @objc func textDidChange(sender: UITextField) {
        if sender == emailTextField {
            viewModel.email = sender.text
        } else {
            viewModel.password = sender.text
        }
        
        updateForm()
    }
    
    @objc func handleShowResetPassword() {
        let controller = ResetPasswordController()
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.email = emailTextField.text
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
        
    // MARK: - Helpers
    
    func configureUI() {
        configureGradientLayer()
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
        
        view.addSubview(iconImage)
        iconImage.centerX(inView: view)
        iconImage.setDimensions(height: 80, width: 120)
        iconImage.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, paddingTop: 32)
        
        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [emailTextField, passwordTextField,
                                                   loginButton, forgotPasswordButton])
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 20
        
        view.addSubview(stack)
        stack.anchor(top: iconImage.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor,
                     right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 32, paddingLeft: 32, paddingRight: 32)
        
        view.addSubview(dontHaveAccountButton)
        dontHaveAccountButton.centerX(inView: view)
        dontHaveAccountButton.anchor(bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
    }
    
    func configureNotificationObservers() {
        emailTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        passwordTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
    }
}

// MARK: - FormViewModel

extension LoginController: FormViewModel {
    func updateForm() {
        loginButton.backgroundColor = viewModel.buttonBackgroundColor
        loginButton.setTitleColor(viewModel.buttonTitleColor, for: .normal)
        loginButton.isEnabled = viewModel.formIsValid
    }
}

// MARK: - ResetPasswordControllerDelegate

extension LoginController: ResetPasswordControllerDelegate {
    func controllerDidSendResetPasswordLink(_ controller: ResetPasswordController) {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        showMessage(withTitle: "Success",
                    message: "We sent a link to your email to reset your password")
    }
}


//Registration Controller: Also works fine and can register users in firebase.


import UIKit

class RegistrationController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    private var viewModel = RegistrationViewModel()
    private var profileImage: UIImage?
    weak var delegate: AuthenticationDelegate?
    
    private let plushPhotoButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "plus_photo"), for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = .white
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleProfilePhotoSelect), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    private let emailTextField: CustomTextField = {
        let tf = CustomTextField(placeholder: "Email")
        tf.keyboardType = .emailAddress
        return tf
    }()
    
    private let passwordTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = CustomTextField(placeholder: "Password")
        tf.isSecureTextEntry = true
        return tf
    }()
    
    private let fullnameTextField = CustomTextField(placeholder: "Fullname")
    private let usernameTextField = CustomTextField(placeholder: "Username")
    
    private let signUpButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Sign Up", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5568627715, green: 0.3529411852, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1).withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.setHeight(50)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSignUp), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.isEnabled = false
        return button
    }()
    
    private let alreadyHaveAccountButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.attributedTitle(firstPart: "Already have an account?", secondPart: "Log In")
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleShowLogin), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureUI()
        configureNotificationObservers()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Actions
    
    @objc func handleSignUp() {
        guard let email = emailTextField.text else { return }
        guard let password = passwordTextField.text else { return }
        guard let fullname = fullnameTextField.text else { return }
        guard let username = usernameTextField.text?.lowercased() else { return }
        guard let profileImage = self.profileImage else { return }
        
        let credentials = AuthCredentials(email: email, password: password,
                                          fullname: fullname, username: username,
                                          profileImage: profileImage)

        AuthService.registerUser(withCredential: credentials) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("DEBUG: Failed to register user \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            self.delegate?.authenticationDidComplete()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func handleShowLogin() {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
    @objc func textDidChange(sender: UITextField) {
        if sender == emailTextField {
            viewModel.email = sender.text
        } else if sender == passwordTextField {
            viewModel.password = sender.text
        } else if sender == fullnameTextField {
            viewModel.fullname = sender.text
        } else {
            viewModel.username = sender.text
        }
        
        updateForm()
    }
    
    @objc func handleProfilePhotoSelect() {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Helpers
    
    func configureUI() {
        configureGradientLayer()
        
        view.addSubview(plushPhotoButton)
        plushPhotoButton.centerX(inView: view)
        plushPhotoButton.setDimensions(height: 140, width: 140)
        plushPhotoButton.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, paddingTop: 32)
        
        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [emailTextField, passwordTextField,
                                                   fullnameTextField, usernameTextField,
                                                   signUpButton])
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 20
        
        view.addSubview(stack)
        stack.anchor(top: plushPhotoButton.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor,
                     right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 32, paddingLeft: 32, paddingRight: 32)
        
        view.addSubview(alreadyHaveAccountButton)
        alreadyHaveAccountButton.centerX(inView: view)
        alreadyHaveAccountButton.anchor(bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
    }
    
    func configureNotificationObservers() {
        emailTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        passwordTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        fullnameTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        usernameTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
    }
}

// MARK: - FormViewModel

extension RegistrationController: FormViewModel {
    func updateForm() {
        signUpButton.backgroundColor = viewModel.buttonBackgroundColor
        signUpButton.setTitleColor(viewModel.buttonTitleColor, for: .normal)
        signUpButton.isEnabled = viewModel.formIsValid
    }
}

// MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

extension RegistrationController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        guard let selectedImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else { return }
        profileImage = selectedImage
        
        plushPhotoButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        plushPhotoButton.clipsToBounds = true
        plushPhotoButton.layer.cornerRadius = plushPhotoButton.frame.width / 2
        plushPhotoButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        plushPhotoButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        plushPhotoButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
        plushPhotoButton.setImage(selectedImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

//Below is the image that appears on the simulator. I have never //seen this. The black screen can be a common occurrence but the //white bar at the bottom is unusual. I can't think of anything //that this can be linked to. I would like to understand the root //cause for this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RQgp.png)

Comment: I can only see that you instantiate a tabBarController and add it to the window. Can you post the relevant code for login/registration?

Comment: Looks like you didn't add any view controllers to your tab view controller. From the screenshot I can see that there's an empty tab view controller (`MainTabController`, I assume).

Comment: The main tab controller is filled with code. Its the first thing that people see when they login. Do you think the issue could be there?

Comment: @Mat I have attached the code for login and registration.

Comment: I noticed as well that your `MainTabController` has no view controllers (or at least tab images) added. That can be a problem. When exactly you get the black view controller? After login, signup or both?

Comment: After login is when I see the issue. Can you please specify where you are seeing the issue in my code with the main tab controller